# Jconsole Password based authentication

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

I am using the JConsole to access my application MBeans. Right now there is no authentication in place. I want to make username/password based authentication when user access it through Jconsole.

I did search on google and tried the few approaches but still Jconsole shows message *"Connection failed: Connection refused: connect"* I have following property set while starting my program

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8222
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\secure\jmxremote.password
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\secure\jmxremote.access
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The password file must be readable **only** by the owner, otherwise it will be ignored. See this link for details:
https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/adminguide/radminjmxenablepwd.html